# Max Value with decimal 99.999 HTML block input

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to make the input takes only the value `99.999`. I don't want to use `MaxLength` because it would not calculate the length of the decimal digits. I don't want to use any other functions that erase when it doesn't match a specific `regex`. I want it to stop it in the input.

```
 function IsCurrencyNoMinus1 (e, thisobj, min, max) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode == 44) || (keyCode == 46) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode))

var inStr = $(thisobj).val();
if (ret && (keyCode == 45) && ((thisobj.selectionStart != 0) || (inStr.indexOf('-') != -1)))
  ret = false;

if (ret && (keyCode == 46) && (inStr != '' && inStr.indexOf('.') != -1) && !(Math.abs(thisobj.selectionStart - thisobj.selectionEnd) == inStr.length)) {
  ret = false;
}

var dotPos = (inStr.indexOf('.') != -1) ? inStr.indexOf('.') : inStr.length;
inStr = inStr.replace(/\,/g, '');
var parts = inStr.split('.');
var maxParts = max.toString().split('.');

if (ret && (inStr != '' && (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57))) {
  if ((parts[0].length >= maxParts[0].length) && ((thisobj.selectionStart - thisobj.selectionEnd) == 0)
    && (thisobj.selectionStart <= dotPos)) {
    ret = false;
  }

  if (ret && (parts[1] != undefined && parts[1].length >= 2) && ((thisobj.selectionStart - thisobj.selectionEnd) == 0)
    && (thisobj.selectionStart > dotPos) && (thisobj.selectionStart <= dotPos + 3))
    ret = false;

  var firstPos = thisobj.selectionStart < thisobj.selectionEnd ? thisobj.selectionStart : thisobj.selectionEnd;
  if (ret && (parts[0].length >= maxParts[0].length) && (parts[1] != undefined && parts[1].length >= 1)
    && ((dotPos - firstPos == 0 && Math.abs(thisobj.selectionStart - thisobj.selectionEnd) < 4)
    || (dotPos - firstPos == 1 && (Math.abs(thisobj.selectionStart - thisobj.selectionEnd) >= 2 && Math.abs(thisobj.selectionStart - thisobj.selectionEnd) < 4))))
    ret = false;
}

if (Number(inStr) > max) {
  thisobj.value = '';
  ret = true;
}

if (Number(inStr) < min) {
  thisobj.value = '';
  ret = true;
}

// var re = new RegExp(/^\(?-?[0-9]{0,12}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?\)?$/)
// if (!re.test(inStr)) {
//    thisobj.value = ""
// }

return ret
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried? :/

Comment: @Jonasw the code i'm using to limit is in out global library and too long and complicated. 

`<input style="height:27px" name="nativeHawaiianPacificIslander" class="numeral form-control text-font-md" type="text" oncopy="return false"
                                                    oncut="return false" onpaste="return false" onkeypress="return IsCurrencyNoMinus(event, this, 0, 99.999)"`

Comment: Cool. And whats not working with it?

Comment: @Jonasw please see the updated post. it is the details for the `IsCurrencyNoMinus` function!

Comment: @Jonasw it blocks the 3rd digit for the decimal from being changed. It rejects the 3rd digit. It is only designed to have 2 digit after the decimal. only 99.99.

Comment: Did you write this code yourself? Have you tried to debug it? People here will not answer some question like "This code doesn't work, help me!". As you said, your code is too long and too complicated. You should tried to debug yourself and narrow down the scope that causes problem. And also, you should explain what your code does so we can understand it quicker and focus on finding out the problem.

Comment: @trgiangvp3 Hi, Thanks for your comment. Yes, I have debugged, and no I wasn't the one who wrote this code, otherwise I would be able to understand it. As I mentioned above, this is a global library function that have been used to some scenarios, but mine is slightly different. I found the solution, and I made an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Please check the code below in case someone needs it.

```
function Format3DigitDecimal(e, thisobj, min, max)
{
    var keyCode = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode
    var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode == 44) || (specialKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) != -1 && e.charCode != e.keyCode))

    var inStr = $(thisobj).val()

    inStr = inStr.replace(/\,/g, '')

    if (ret && (inStr != '' && (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57)))
    {
        if ((inStr.length >= max.toString().length) && ((thisobj.selectionStart - thisobj.selectionEnd) == 0))
        {
            ret = false
        }
    }

    if (ret && (inStr != '' && (keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57)))
    {
        if ((inStr.length == 2) && ((thisobj.selectionStart - thisobj.selectionEnd) == 0))
        {
            ret = false
        }
    }

    return ret
}
```